# Change default CSS class of Table component on SAPUI

Tags: sapui5

I'm using [sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Table.html) component. I'v noticed that my cells have default css class `sapMListTblCell` nd hegight of rows look me very large:

[image]

I want  height of rows is more adjusted to cell's content.

I've seen [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Selection/preview). In it cells have another css class: `sapUiTableTd`

I want my cells of my table have that css class. I think I should change css class of my table to `sapUiTableCnt` (like the example). But it doesn't work.

Please, someone could tell me What I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells have that height because UI5 is mobile first - controls are optimized for working on mobile phones. The spacing / size of various controls depends on a so called [content density](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e54f729da8e3405fae5e4fe8ae7784c1.html). Normally, you should check whether or not the user is using a mobile device and set the corresponding content density to your root view. By convention, this check is done [inside the Component](https://github.com/serban-petrescu/smta/blob/master/ui/diplomaadmintransport/Component.js#L59) and then called by the [root view's controller](https://github.com/serban-petrescu/smta/blob/master/ui/diplomaadmintransport/controller/App.controller.js#L36).

So, setting a compact density class would most likely solve your problem. You can also create your own density class specifically for tables (and other controls that you may want to target). You can set the compact density and specify e.g. the height of the cells:

CSS style:

```css
.sapUiSizeCompact.myCustomSize .sapMListTblCell {
    height: 1rem
}
```

View:

```xml
 <Table class="sapUiSizeCompact myCustomSize" />
```

You can find a working version here (comparison between cozy, compact and our custom density class): https://jsfiddle.net/z2gkvde0/1/.

Comment: Could you explain because in the examples cells have css class sapUiTableTd and not sapMListTblCell as in my case?

Comment: There are two different Table controls in UI5: sap.m.Table and sap.ui.table.Table. Both are "content density aware" (i.e. they respect the content density classes as explained above). The example that you linked in NOT sap.m.Table, but sap.ui.table.Table, hence the different classes. You should not attempt to use sap.ui.table CSS classes for the sap.m controls as the behavior might change between versions (the classes are not built to eb used like that).

Comment: Thanks for your response! @SerbanPetrescu